# Making an analytics page using impressionist gem in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, analytics

I'm using the gem [impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) to track how users interact with my product. It seems that typically the gem is used to determine how many pageviews a specific view gets. For example, how many views a specific auction gets on an auction website. [Here's a full example of that.](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1458/track-page-views-the-smart-way-with-the-impressionist-gem)

Except I need to do something a bit different. I need to see how many times a specific controller#action is hit and by who. I didn't have much of an issue setting up a table that displays this information. It's of the format:

```
Controller#action | Total Views | Unique Users

      user#edit   |     500     |      44

     tweet#show   |    1097     |      50
```

What I would like to do now is link the controller#action to a 'show' page of sorts so that I can list all of the users who have visited that controller#action.

So for example, clicking the tweet#show link will bring me to a page showing a table like such:

```
User | Pageviews | Average Time on Page
 05  |    86     |         4:57
 47  |    12     |         1:22
```

The issue I'm having is the proper way to set up the routing for this. Will the url have to have a format of: /analytics/user/edit ? Or is there a more rails-y way of doing this? I've tried a bit of googling but I couldn't find an answer.